# How to get the current time in server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using asp.net mvc3.

`Scenario:`

`(PC1) as server side or where I publish my project` and `(PC2) as client or where I am using my current PC`. In `PC1` the current time is `10:00 AM` and in `PC2` is `01:00 PM` with the same or different date/s. I have a button in my veiw `(cshtml)` for getting the time of the `PC1` after i click the button.

So far I tried the code `DateTime.Now()` in controller but it is getting what the current time in my current PC?. `Not sure about this one`.

How to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: This is now the 3rd time you have asked this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime.UtcNow()` at client and server while saving the date and time. When you need to show date on your UI convert it to specific time zone using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc`

Comment: I manage to display the current date by using this `<label for="">@DateTime.Now.ToString()</label>` and thanks to YonF. My problem now is the time

Comment: @DateTime.Now.ToString() will give you time as well. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to fitch the datetime from your server by using (SELECT GETUTCDATE();).  and it is better to save your datetime to your queries by (GETDATE()).

Good luck.

Comment: This is SQL not C# ... And this is a C# question. So how can this be an answer?